# Heavy load web service because of blocked Phusion Passenger queues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, nginx, passenger, sidekiq

We are developing a Web service using Ruby 2 on Rails 4, Mongoid 4, MongoDB 2.6. It uses Sidekiq 3.3.0 and Redis 2.8 and is running on Phusion Passenger 5.0.4 + Nginx 1.7.10. It only serves mobile clients & AngularJS web client via JSON APIs.

Normally everything works fine, APIs are processed and responded under 1s. But in rush hours, the service is heavy load (APIs are rendered as `503 Service Unavailable`). Below are our Nginx & Mongoid config:

#### Nginx config

```
passenger_root /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/passenger-4.0.53;
#passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
passenger_max_pool_size 70;
passenger_min_instances 1;
passenger_max_requests 20; # A workaround if apps are mem-leaking
passenger_pool_idle_time 300;
passenger_max_instances_per_app 30;
passenger_pre_start http://production_domain/;

## Note: there're 2 apps with the same config
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name production_domain;
  passenger_enabled on;
  root /home/deployer/app_name-production/current/public;

  more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'
  more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD';
  more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';

  if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
    # more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *';
    # add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    # add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    # add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,X-FooA$
    # add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
    # add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
    # add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
    return 200;
  }

  access_log /var/log/nginx/app_name-production.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/app_name-production.error.log;

  error_page 404 /404.html;
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root /etc/nginx/html/;
  }
  rails_env production;
}
```

#### Mongoid config

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      another:
      uri: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/database_name
test:
  sessions:
    default:
      another:
      uri: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/database_name
      options:
        pool_size: 10
        pool_timeout: 15
        retry_interval: 1
        max_retries: 30
        refresh_interval: 10
        timeout: 15
staging:
  sessions:
    default:
      another:
      uri: mongodb://staging_domain/staging_database
      options:
        pool_size: 10
        pool_timeout: 15
        retry_interval: 1
        max_retries: 30
        refresh_interval: 10
        timeout: 15
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      another:
      uri: mongodb://production_domain/production_database
      options:
        pool_size: 30
        pool_timeout: 15
        retry_interval: 1
        max_retries: 30
        refresh_interval: 10
        timeout: 15
```

#### Sidekiq config

and Passenger logs when heavy load:

```
Version : 5.0.4
Date    : 2015-04-04 09:31:14 +0700
Instance: MxPcaaBy (nginx/1.7.10 Phusion_Passenger/5.0.4)

----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 120
Processes     : 62
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
/home/deployer/memo_rails-staging/current/public (staging)#default:
  App root: /home/deployer/memo_rails-staging/current
  Requests in queue: 0
  * PID: 20453   Sessions: 0       Processed: 639     Uptime: 14h 34m 26s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 184M    Last used: 14s ago
  * PID: 402     Sessions: 0       Processed: 5       Uptime: 13h 0m 42s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 171M    Last used: 23m 35s
  * PID: 16081   Sessions: 0       Processed: 3       Uptime: 10h 26m 9s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 163M    Last used: 24m 9s a
  * PID: 30300   Sessions: 0       Processed: 1       Uptime: 4h 19m 43s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 164M    Last used: 24m 15s

/home/deployer/memo_rails-production/current/public (production)#default:
  App root: /home/deployer/memo_rails-production/current
  Requests in queue: 150
  * PID: 25924   Sessions: 1       Processed: 841     Uptime: 20m 49s
    CPU: 3%      Memory  : 182M    Last used: 7m 58s ago
  * PID: 25935   Sessions: 1       Processed: 498     Uptime: 20m 49s
    CPU: 2%      Memory  : 199M    Last used: 5m 40s ago
  * PID: 25948   Sessions: 1       Processed: 322     Uptime: 20m 49s
    CPU: 1%      Memory  : 200M    Last used: 7m 57s ago
  * PID: 25960   Sessions: 1       Processed: 177     Uptime: 20m 49s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 158M    Last used: 19s ago
  * PID: 25972   Sessions: 1       Processed: 115     Uptime: 20m 48s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 151M    Last used: 7m 56s ago
  * PID: 25987   Sessions: 1       Processed: 98      Uptime: 20m 48s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 179M    Last used: 7m 56s ago
  * PID: 25998   Sessions: 1       Processed: 77      Uptime: 20m 48s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 145M    Last used: 7m 2s ago
  * PID: 26012   Sessions: 1       Processed: 97      Uptime: 20m 48s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 167M    Last used: 19s ago
  * PID: 26024   Sessions: 1       Processed: 42      Uptime: 20m 47s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 148M    Last used: 7m 55s ago
  * PID: 26038   Sessions: 1       Processed: 44      Uptime: 20m 47s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 164M    Last used: 1m 0s ago
  * PID: 26050   Sessions: 1       Processed: 29      Uptime: 20m 47s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 142M    Last used: 7m 54s ago
  * PID: 26063   Sessions: 1       Processed: 41      Uptime: 20m 47s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 168M    Last used: 1m 1s ago
  * PID: 26075   Sessions: 1       Processed: 23      Uptime: 20m 47s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 126M    Last used: 7m 51s ago
  * PID: 26087   Sessions: 1       Processed: 19      Uptime: 20m 46s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 120M    Last used: 7m 50s ago
  * PID: 26099   Sessions: 1       Processed: 37      Uptime: 20m 46s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 131M    Last used: 7m 3s ago
  * PID: 26111   Sessions: 1       Processed: 20      Uptime: 20m 46s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 110M    Last used: 7m 49s ago
  * PID: 26126   Sessions: 1       Processed: 28      Uptime: 20m 46s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 172M    Last used: 1m 56s ago
  * PID: 26141   Sessions: 1       Processed: 20      Uptime: 20m 45s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 107M    Last used: 7m 19s ago
  * PID: 26229   Sessions: 1       Processed: 20      Uptime: 20m 21s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 110M    Last used: 11s ago
  * PID: 26241   Sessions: 1       Processed: 9       Uptime: 20m 21s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 105M    Last used: 7m 47s ago
  * PID: 26548   Sessions: 1       Processed: 23      Uptime: 19m 14s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 125M    Last used: 7m 44s ago
  * PID: 27465   Sessions: 1       Processed: 30      Uptime: 15m 23s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 109M    Last used: 2m 22s ago
  * PID: 27501   Sessions: 1       Processed: 28      Uptime: 15m 18s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 117M    Last used: 7m 15s ago
  * PID: 27511   Sessions: 1       Processed: 34      Uptime: 15m 17s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 144M    Last used: 5m 40s ago
  * PID: 27522   Sessions: 1       Processed: 30      Uptime: 15m 17s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 110M    Last used: 26s ago
  * PID: 27533   Sessions: 1       Processed: 38      Uptime: 15m 17s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 110M    Last used:"4m 44s ago
  * PID: 27555   Sessions: 1       Processed: 27      Uptime: 15m 15s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 120M    Last used: 1m 29s ago
  * PID: 27570   Sessions: 1       Processed: 21      Uptime: 15m 14s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 107M    Last used: 7m 1s ago
  * PID: 27590   Sessions: 1       Processed: 8       Uptime: 15m 13s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 105M    Last used: 7m 34s ago
  * PID: 27599   Sessions: 1       Processed: 13      Uptime: 15m 13s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 107M    Last used: 7m 0s ago
  * PID: 27617   Sessions: 1       Processed: 26      Uptime: 15m 12s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 114M    Last used: 4m 49s ago
  * PID: 27633   Sessions: 1       Processed: 19      Uptime: 15m 11s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 137M    Last used: 1m 14s ago
  * PID: 27643   Sessions: 1       Processed: 15      Uptime: 15m 11s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 132M    Last used: 6m 19s ago
  * PID: 27661   Sessions: 1       Processed: 23      Uptime: 15m 10s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 112M    Last used: 9s ago
  * PID: 27678   Sessions: 1       Processed: 24      Uptime: 15m 9s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 108M    Last used: 6m 53s ago
  * PID: 27692   Sessions: 1       Processed: 9       Uptime: 15m 9s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 105M    Last used: 7m 22s ago
  * PID: 28400   Sessions: 1       Processed: 19      Uptime: 12m 45s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 111M    Last used: 1m 25s ago
  * PID: 28415   Sessions: 1       Processed: 26      Uptime: 12m 45s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 149M    Last used: 3m 45s ago
  * PID: 28439   Sessions: 1       Processed: 14      Uptime: 12m 44s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 106M    Last used: 59s ago
  * PID: 28477   Sessions: 1       Processed: 12      Uptime: 12m 42s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 108M    Last used: 1m 34s ago
  * PID: 28495   Sessions: 1       Processed: 14      Uptime: 12m 41s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 108M    Last used: 18s ago
  * PID: 29315   Sessions: 1       Processed: 7       Uptime: 10m 1s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 107M    Last used: 7m 0s ago
  * PID: 29332   Sessions: 1       Processed: 13      Uptime: 10m 0s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 108M    Last used: 5m 39s ago
  * PID: 29341   Sessions: 1       Processed: 7       Uptime: 10m 0s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 105M    Last used: 6m 53s ago
  * PID: 29353   Sessions: 1       Processed: 11      Uptime: 10m 0s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 119M    Last used: 5m 4s ago
  * PID: 29366   Sessions: 1       Processed: 16      Uptime: 9m 59s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 119M    Last used: 3m 13s ago
  * PID: 29377   Sessions: 1       Processed: 10      Uptime: 9m 59s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 113M    Last used: 1m 34s ago
  * PID: 29388   Sessions: 1       Processed: 2       Uptime: 9m 59s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 97M     Last used: 7m 28s ago
  * PID: 29400   Sessions: 1       Processed: 6       Uptime: 9m 59s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 103M    Last used: 6m 53s ago
  * PID: 29422   Sessions: 1       Processed: 17      Uptime: 9m 58s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 132M    Last used: 1m 24s ago
  * PID: 29438   Sessions: 1       Processed: 1       Uptime: 9m 57s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 96M     Last used: 6m 52s ago
  * PID: 29451   Sessions: 1       Processed: 21      Uptime: 9m 56s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 133M    Last used: 2m 10s ago
  * PID: 29463   Sessions: 1       Processed: 19      Uptime: 9m 56s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 111M    Last used: 27s ago
  * PID: 29477   Sessions: 1       Processed: 23      Uptime: 9m 56s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 117M    Last used: 14s ago
  * PID: 30625   Sessions: 1       Processed: 7       Uptime: 6m 49s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 106M    Last used: 1m 21s ago
  * PID: 30668   Sessions: 1       Processed: 2       Uptime: 6m 44s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 105M    Last used: 1m 13s ago
  * PID: 30706   Sessions: 1       Processed: 16      Uptime: 6m 43s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 148M    Last used: 1m 11s ago
  * PID: 30718   Sessions: 1       Processed: 12      Uptime: 6m 43s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 112M    Last used: 1m 16s ago
```

I have some questions:

1. It seems to be that someone with slow internet connection is requesting our service, leading to Passenger processes is blocked. We have to restart Nginx to get the web service works again. Anyone has experiences with this?
2. We also use Sidekiq as worker queues. Most of our Workers are implemented without hitting MongoDB. They work fine.

But there are 2 Workers we use to update User's data, which query, update & insert data into the database. We've tried to optimize these all tasks using MongoDB bulk commands ([update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) & [insert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/)).

Normally, when a small amount of users request the web service, the Workers work fine, busy queues are processed in about 1 minutes, but when it receives more requests, busy queues block the whole system. We have to restart the Nginx, again, to get it works. Below are Sidekiq config:

```
development:
  :concurrency: 5
  :logfile: ./log/sidekiq_development.log
  :pidfile: ./log/sidekiq.pid
staging:
  :concurrency: 5
  :logfile: ./log/sidekiq_staging.log
  :pidfile: ./log/sidekiq.pid
production:
  :concurrency: 15
  :logfile: ./log/sidekiq_production.log
  :pidfile: ./log/sidekiq.pid
:queues:
  - ...
```

We don't have any experiences with those problems. Anyone has any ideas?

## Update 1:

After some monitorings when server is heavy load, we got this result: the MongoDB processes have many faults & stacked read queues, below are what `mongostat` logged during the downtime:

```
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults      locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn       time
    *0      2     *0     *0       0     4|0       0    79g   160g  3.36g    137   memo_v2:2.6%          0      17|0     8|0    36k     8k    61   15:05:22
    *0      6     *0     *0       0     1|0       0    79g   160g  3.38g    144   memo_v2:2.1%          0      30|0     3|0   722b    11k    61   15:05:23
  1595     15      1     *0       0     5|0       0    79g   160g  3.41g    139  memo_v2:19.7%          0      20|0     8|0   164k   179k    61   15:05:25
     1     18      2     *0       1     6|0       0    79g   160g  3.38g    198  memo_v2:14.4%          0      31|0     1|0     3k   122k    61   15:05:26
     2     20      4     *0       0     7|0       0    79g   160g  3.38g    169   memo_v2:8.6%          0      29|0     1|0     3k   157k    61   15:05:27
     1      6     23     *0       0     4|0       0    79g   160g  3.39g    190  memo_v2:18.7%          0      32|0     1|0     1k    63k    61   15:05:28
     1      4     42     *0       0     4|0       0    79g   160g   3.1g    115  memo_v2:35.9%          0      30|0     0|1     1k    20k    61   15:05:29
     1      5     51     *0       0     4|0       0    79g   160g  3.11g    177  memo_v2:30.0%          0      28|0     1|0     1k    23k    61   15:05:30
    *0      6     20     *0       0     2|0       0    79g   160g  3.12g    174  memo_v2:40.9%          0      28|0     1|0    15k     7k    61   15:05:31
     2      9     *0     *0       1     7|0       0    79g   160g   3.1g    236   memo_v2:4.4%          0      26|0     2|0     2k    31k    61   15:05:32
```

Anyone faced this before?

Comment: passenger 5.0.5 and 5.0.6 have quite a few bug fixes - have you tried them?

Comment: Your passenger-status output seems to imply that your app is stuck somewhere. Have you tried debugging that? This guide should help: http://old.blog.phusion.nl/2012/09/21/the-right-way-to-deal-with-frozen-processes-on-unix/

Comment: @Hongli: here is stacktrace of a busy process, https://gist.github.com/hainp/6160a7d5ab3395aadbae. It is an output of `passenger-status` & `rb_stacktrace()` commands. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: Hi, I've updated my question with `mongostat` logs during the downtime, maybe helpful for everyone who's familiar with this. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to post a comment, so I'll have to add a very lacklustre answer.

I don't have any experience with the stack, but if you are correct in that slow clients are the cause of the passenger issues then I'd suggest that you **ensure there is adequate buffering in front of the passenger processes**.

For nginx, the important setting looks to be proxy_buffers. The section titled "Using Buffers to Free Up Backend Servers" in following article talks about the nginx module: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-http-proxying-load-balancing-buffering-and-caching

For the mongodb issue, it sounds like you just need to dig a little deeper. If you can find where the issue is happening in the code, the solution will probably present itself. The article linked by Hongli looks very good for that.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I agree it barely answers the question, but the document you linked states that I can't add comments until I have 50 reputation, which is in line with my experience. Can't provide quality answers without clarification, but can't get clarification without providing quality answers. It's a bit of a catch-22 for a new poster.

Ordinarily, I'd just move on but I was specifically asked by an acquaintance of the OP to give an answer to this question.

Comment: Yes, it can seem like a bit of a Catch-22 but it is very much possible. It is just a matter of looking around for questions that don't need clarification or waiting for someone else to ask for clarification (because if you don't understand what is being asked then chances are everyone else won't either). So, even though it seems like a challenge to get to 50 rep, one can do it pretty quickly.